# Git error: failed to push some refs

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-branch

Накосячил видимо где-то.
Сделал
git add .
git commit -m "text"
git branch -M main
git push

вывод в терминале:

```
To https://github.com/RussianTech-IT/RuTech-web.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/RussianTech-IT/RuTech-web.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: В представленном тексте написано что не так и что надо сделать....

Comment: Написано же -- прежде чем пушать свои изменения, следует сделать `git pull`, так как состояние удаленного репозитория изменилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решено и закрыто.

Решение:**

`git push --force`